Asian rom com about secretly wealthy man falling in love with regular/ poor women who doesn't know he's rich
I'm looking for a movie whose story follows a smug Lady as she meets and befriends what turns out to be the heir to a successful phone company.
The man keeps his identity a secret as they start to connect, the lady, when asked if she is seeing someone, then proceeds to "lie" about how her boyfriend is rich and successful, upon being asking for proof she asks the guy to pretend to be her wealthy boyfriend and show up to a party, since he is of course rich, he shows up to a party in a fancy car and nice suit.
The lady still thinking it's part of the act rolled with it until the truth is revealed in a heart- warming ending.
Im certain it's a romantic comedy. I saw it with subtitles, it's either Korean or Chinese (not to sure). It  aired at least before 2015.

Sounds matching to indian movie Ghajini, It is loosely based on top of epic movie Memento - common stuff being that in both movies, the main character is suffering from short term memory loss.
Plot is based around a medical-student who is researching on a rich businessmen turned short-term-memory-loss patient. Chain of events leading him to this state involve a romantic relation and death of his beloved.
From the description :

Medical student, Sunita, is driven by curiosity to study the case of
  Sanjay Singhania, who is afflicted with short-term memory loss. She
  runs into him, befriends him, and finds out that he is out to kill a
  seemingly benevolent citizen, Ghajini Dharmatma. After warning the
  latter of the impending danger, she subsequently comes across a number
  of diaries written by Sanjay and attempts to put together a jigsaw
  puzzle as to how a successful and wealthy businessman became a crazed
  recluse, who re-lives his past through tattoos on his body, notes and
  Polaroid photographs on the wall of his Hiranandani Complex flat, and
  his sole obsession of carrying out his deadly mission - little knowing
  that Ghajini and his goons are out to erase every bit of evidence he
  has gathered and thus ensure that he ends up remembering nothing


There is also a 1991 Hong Kong movie called "Dances with Dragon" (Ref: Wikipedia Link) with similar plot.

The actress uses a traditional eye-glasses as a sign of an old-fashioned lady in the beginning.
There is a birthday party middle plot that the tycoon was original poorly dressed  but he switched to fancy suit later and use million dollar to buy a lottery ticket as a gift. Finally, he use helicopter as vehicle to send the girl back home but tell her it's mainly a costume/props like a movie production from a friend. 
His true tycoon identity  was revealed until the final charity auction event to purchase the island' land for business development and promise to give a supermarket to the girl in return her favor. 


This should be the movie Ghajini (Tamil version, Hindi version).
The film's main plot was adapted from Christopher Nolan's 2000 neo-noir film Memento.

You might want to add in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
